# How to compare 2 characters of a string in assembler?

Tags: assembly, emu8086

I am trying to write a program where a string with words is entered. Then we enter the word to be deleted. In a loop, I'm trying to compare the characters of the first and second string, however the condition keeps returning positive always

**I am using emulator emu8086**

```
name test
.model small
.stack 100h
.data       
    wrd_ask db "word: $" 
    string_ask db "string: $"
    
    w_buffer db 255           
    wrd db 256 dup('$')
    
    s_buffer db 255    
    string db 256 dup('$')
.code

macro convert buffer
    push ax
    push dx
    lea dx, buffer
    mov ah, 0Ah
    int 21h 
    pop dx
    pop ax
endm

start: 
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax
    
    mov dx, offset string_ask
    mov ah, 09h
    int 21h
    convert s_buffer
    
    mov dx, offset wrd_ask
    mov ah, 09h
    int 21h
    convert w_buffer
    
    mov si, 0
    mov di, 0  
    mov cx, 255
     
cycle:  
    inc si                
    inc di
    cmp string[si], wrd[di]
    je same

    same:
        mov dl, wrd[di]
        mov ah, 02h
        int 21h  
    
    LOOP cycle
end start
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> cmp string[si], wrd[di]
> ```

You can't compare two memory bytes like that. The instruction set does not allow it. You need to load one of them in a register before comparing with the other:

```
mov  al, string[si]
cmp  al, wrd[di]
```

> ```
> je same
>
> same:
> ```

You need something in between here (whatever you want in case of 'not equal'). Else, regardless of the outcome of the comparison, will the code at *same* get executed.

---

Try the following:

```
cycle:  
    inc  si                
    inc  di
    mov  dl, string[si]
    cmp  dl, wrd[di]
    jne  different
    mov  ah, 02h
    int  21h  
    loop cycle
same:
    ...
    mov  ax, 4C00h
    int  21h
different:
    ...
    mov  ax, 4C00h
    int  21h
```

Use the sentence: "stackoverflow rocks"
Use the word: "stackunderflow"

Observe the result "stack" (the first difference is between "o" and "u".

Comment: If call "different" cycle will be stopped

Comment: @user20586260 Indeed, the demo program stops anyway, but you can see that the comparison worked, can you. Now you continue with whatever you were tasked to write... Good luck.